# Difference between arr[index] and calling the variable equal to arr[index]

Tags: python, arrays, pointers, reference

This question regards whether python treats its "names" as pointers or references, which I have yet to find a clear explanation for.

Consider the following scenario:

```
L = [[][]]
L1 = L[1]
L1 = [1] # Interested in what happens after this line
print L # L = [[], []]
```

However,
if we change the above line of interest to L[1] = [1], namely the code block below:

```
L = [[][]]
L1 = L[1]
L[1] = [1] # Interested in what happens after this line
print L # L = [[], [1]]
```

The above the code blocks only differ by the third line, where we use L[1] (indexing the array directly) or L1 (the variable which we assigned as L1 = L[1]).

So what are L1 and L[1] in essence? What's the difference? Is one of them reference, and the other not?

Thanks for addressing this confusion!

Comment: Read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L1 = b` stores `b` in the variable `L1`. So `L1 = L[1]` and `L1 = [1]` just change what `L1` points to. The second assignment doesn't care what was in `L1` before.

`L[a] = b` is essentially equivalent to `L.__setitem__(a, b)`. So while it looks similar to variable assignment, it's a completely different kind of thing. There is no name/variable/pointer/reference `L[1]`.

Also, in your second block of code, `L1 = L[1]` isn't having any effect. You can remove it and the outcome will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Python assignments do not create copies of the original object, but instead create bindings between the two. Consider your original example:

```
 >> L = [[],[]]
 >> L1 = L[1]
 >> L1.append(1)
 >> L[1].append(2)
 L1: [1, 2]
 L: [[], [1, 2]]
```

In your original example, you were overriding the copies by performing fresh assignments to new lists.
Hope this helps!